# Replace multiple files in sub directories with file from a different directory

Tags: windows, batch-file, replace, cmd

I would like to take a file named `test1.hfl` from one directory and replace all the existing `test1.hfl` files inside the sub directories of the folder runs in my c drive.

I have started the batch file with the following code:

```
FOR /R C:\Users\----\Documents\Train\Runs\ %%I IN (*test1.hfl) DO COPY /Y C:\Users\----\Documents\test1.hfl %%~fI
```

But it doesn't work.

Please let me know if you can see something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
cd /d "C:\Users\----\Documents\Train\Runs"
FOR /D /R \ %%a IN (*) do if exist "%%~a\test1.hfl" echo copy /y "test1.hfl" "%%~a"
```

Look at the output and remove the word `echo` if it looks good.

*<sub>[Accepting an answer - how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)</sub>*

Comment: Thanks, but i'm only looking to copy it into folders that already have the file in it.

Comment: In the code above how does it know which is the new test1.hfl file and where to get it from? My new test1.hfl file is in the folder C:\Users\----\Documents\
It does work though. THANKS!!

Comment: Sorry that was a bit premature - it says the system cannot find the file specified

Comment: the code takes the file from the current folder. The current folder is set with `cd /d "C:\Users\----\Documents\Train\Runs"` . If the message appears `file not found` the folder setting is wrong (ie. there is not such file).

Comment: Right! Okay I had it set to the wrong current folder. It now works properly!! Thanks a bunch! I would vote up but i have no reputation :(